# SASS won't build in Sublime Text 2 [Errno 2] No such File or Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, sublimetext2, compass-sass

I've scoured all other posts on this subject to no avail.

I've created a .scss file, installed sass, compass and I'm on OSX so I have ruby installed, I did install the latest version about a year ago however.

When I cmd + b to build my .scss I get this error:

```
Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'sass', u'--update', u'/Users/administrator/Desktop/style.scss:/Users/administrator/Desktop/style.css', u'--stop-on-error', u'--no-cache']]
[dir:  /Users/administrator/Desktop]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Here is what is in my Ruby.sublime-build file:

```
{
"cmd": ["ruby", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.ruby",
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason the build command isn't working is because Sublime can't find your `sass` executable. If you open Terminal and type `which sass` at the prompt, it'll most likely give you a location along the lines of `/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/sass` - it's location on my system. As you can see right in the output you posted, Sublime is only looking in a few directories for it, unfortunately it's not in any of the directories being searched.

There are two ways around this. The first is to modify your **SASS** `.sublime-build` file (`Ruby.sublime-build` has nothing to do with this) to point to the correct location of `sass`. The second is to run

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/sass /usr/local/bin/sass
```

at the command prompt (obviously substituting the correct path for your system) to create a symlink to sass in `/usr/local/bin`, which is one of the directories Sublime is searching. Either one will do fine, although if you ever update your ruby version and the sass gem, you'll need to update either the build file or the symlink.

Comment: I followed these instructions with no luck I tried "which sass" then pasted the response in to  "sudo ln -s /path/to/sass /usr/local/bin/sass" then typed my password - i restarted sublime and tried to build again with the same build error

Comment: @pixeltooth - what is the full text of the error on Sublime? Also, which plugin are you using to build your sass? Give me the URL to it, if possible. Thanks

Comment: After I posted the above: I ran sublime from the terminal using subl - which made the plugin work - if I run from the launcher it doesn't work. I understand that the launcher uses the wrong path, whereas the terminal has a variable path therefore works..

Comment: @pixeltooth - that's correct, running an OS X program from Terminal allows it to inherit your `$PATH` and other environment variables. If you're comfortable doing it, check out my instructions [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89076/how-to-set-the-path-osx-applications-use/89077#89077) on permanently changing the `PATH` setting seen by all Dock-launched apps.