# Errno 2 No Such file or directory Sass not compiling in subilme text 2

Tags: css, macos, sass, sublimetext2

I've found a few related posts but none match my specific problem and I think i've tried everything.

This is the error I get:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'sass', u'--update', u'/Users/ryanwaters/Code/raw_portfolio/public/css/stylesheet.css.scss:/Users/ryanwaters/Code/raw_portfolio/public/css/stylesheet.css.css', u'--stop-on-error', u'--style', u'compressed']]
[dir:  /Users/ryanwaters/Code/raw_portfolio/public/css]
[path: /usr/local/bin/sass]
[Finished]
```

When I put `which sass` in command line I get `/Users/ryanwaters/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/sass`

I've changed the pass several times and still can't figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 6):

This seems pretty simple, but my problem was that I upgraded my mac's OS to Yosemite. I must've done something wrong, because my sass installation didn't carry over.

So, Sublime was throwing this error because it couldn't find sass. I reinstalled it, and everything worked as before.

Answer (score 2):

This question is nearly an exact duplicate of [SASS won't build in Sublime Text 2 [Errno 2] No such File or Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610553/sass-wont-build-in-sublime-text-2-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory) from several days ago. If you look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626924/1426065) there, you'll see that you need to change the path to `sass`. You can either edit your `SASS.sublime-build` file and change the `"cmd":` line to point to `/Users/ryanwaters/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/sass`, or you can make a symlink to it in one of Sublime's default search directories, like `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Here is my sass.sublime-build file   `{

 "cmd": ["/Users/ryanwaters/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/sass", "sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"],
 "selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
 "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

 "osx":
 {
  "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
 },

 "windows":
 {
  "shell": "true"
 }

}`
And now i'm getting this error in sublime
`[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 127]env: ruby: No such file or directory`

Comment: Remove `"sass",` from the cmd - you're calling it on itself. It should read `"cmd": ["/Users/ryan.../sass", "--update", ...`

Comment: Removed "sass", still getting `[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]env: ruby: No such file or directory` 
PS. Your ST2 neon color theme is rad!, just installed

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually specify the "**path**" and "**gemPath**" settings in the User Settings file for SassBeautify (e.g. "`/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/SassBeautify.sublime-settings`"). .

#### Here are the exact steps I followed to resolve the issue:

(derived from the [documentation](https://github.com/badsyntax/SassBeautify#settings) in the package repository).

1. Open up a terminal
2. Run: `echo $PATH`
3. Copy the *entire* output of that command
4. Open the SassBeautify settings file ("**Preferences**" -> "**Package Settings**" -> "**SassBeautify**" -> "**Settings – User**")
5. Paste the previously copied output wrapped in quotes into the '**path**' setting (or add a "**path**" setting if it doesn't already exist)
6. Go back to your terminal and run: `echo $GEM_PATH`
7. Copy the *entire* output of that command
8. Go Back to the settings file
9. Paste the previously copied output wrapped in quotes into the '**gemPath**' setting (or add a "**gemPath**" setting if it doesn't already exist)
10. Save the settings file and restart Sublime Text

Here's a screenshot of my SassBeautify settings file for reference:

[image]