# Can't build SASS in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I followed everything here: [SASS won't build in Sublime Text 2 [Errno 2] No such File or Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610553/sass-wont-build-in-sublime-text-2-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

I tried symlink and also changing the path code in the SASS.sublime-build file to point to my sass install
like this:

```
{
"cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-   cache"],
"selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
"line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

"osx":
{
    "path": "/Users/Andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/sass"
},

"windows":
{
    "shell": "true"
}

}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
[Errno 20] Not a directory
[cmd: [u'sass', u'--update', u'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Alloy-     Engineering/sass/styles.scss:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Alloy-    Engineering/sass/styles.css', u'--stop- on-error', u'--no-cache']]
[dir: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Alloy-Engineering/sass]
[path: /Users/Andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/sass]
[Finished]
```

Also, if I change my path in SASS.sublime-build back to:

```
"path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

I get this error:

```
env: ruby_executable_hooks: Not a directory
```

Running MAC OS Mavericks and Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure this out. I did however get it running after installing a fresh version of Yosemite on my Macbook Pro.